# Matplotlib set_data for errorbar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib's `line2D` objects, such as those returned by a call to `plot`, have a convenient method, `set_data`, that let's me quickly update the values plotted by a single line without affecting the rest of the plot or the formatting of the line.

```
#sample plot
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
p = plot(arange(10),arange(10))[0]

#now update the data
p.set_data(arange(10),arange(10)+2)
draw()
```

Is there any relatively simple (few lines of code) way to do the same with an `errorbar` plot? I'd like to be able to set up a complicated plot with assorted text, arrows, lines, etc., then quickly cycle just the errorbar portion of the plot through several different sets of data.

The object returned by `errorbar` seems to be pretty complex and so far my attempts at deleting and redrawing have failed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's any easy way to do this. You can access the lines that make up the plot via the `.lines` attribute of the `ErrorbarContainer` object, which gives you a tuple of `(xyline, caplines, errorbarlines)`. It's easy enough to call `xyline.set_data()`. The awkwardness begins with having to manually work out the new xy positions for each of the `caplines`. You'd have to do the same thing for the `errorbarlines`, and since these are a tuple of `LineCollection`s, you would need to pass a sequence of `(x0, y0), (x1, y1), ... (xm, ym)` to the `.set_segments()` method.

Comment: You might consider making a feature request at the [numpy Github repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy).

Comment: Feature request made! Except I made it on the matplotlib Github repository instead of numpy. 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3366

Comment: Ooops, yes that would make more sense...

Comment: According a response I got to the matplotlib feature request, this is on the docket for version 1.5.x.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - the broader changes proposed in [MEP25](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/wiki/MEP25) look fantastic

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [the help from @tacaswell](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4556).
Below is the python function that can both update `xerr` and `yerr`, as well as the `x_data` and `y_data` for the baseline plotting:

```
def adjustErrbarxy(self, errobj, x, y, x_error, y_error):
    ln, (errx_top, errx_bot, erry_top, erry_bot), (barsx, barsy) = errobj
    x_base = x
    y_base = y

    xerr_top = x_base + x_error
    xerr_bot = x_base - x_error
    yerr_top = y_base + y_error
    yerr_bot = y_base - y_error

    errx_top.set_xdata(xerr_top)
    errx_bot.set_xdata(xerr_bot)
    errx_top.set_ydata(y_base)
    errx_bot.set_ydata(y_base)

    erry_top.set_xdata(x_base)
    erry_bot.set_xdata(x_base)
    erry_top.set_ydata(yerr_top)
    erry_bot.set_ydata(yerr_bot)

    new_segments_x = [np.array([[xt, y], [xb,y]]) for xt, xb, y in zip(xerr_top, xerr_bot, y_base)]
    new_segments_y = [np.array([[x, yt], [x,yb]]) for x, yt, yb in zip(x_base, yerr_top, yerr_bot)]
    barsx.set_segments(new_segments_x)
    barsy.set_segments(new_segments_y)
```

The first input parameter (`self` is for python class)  is the already created `errorbar` plot handler, that is also the object whose properties need to be updated; `x` and `y` are the updated `numpy` arrays which should be shown the average values along `x` and `y` axis; the last two parameters `x_error` and `y_error` are the `errorbar` ranges calculated for `x` and `y` arrays. If only the errorbars are need to be updated, the `x_base` and `y_base` should be writen as `ln.get_xdata()` and `ln.get_ydata()`, respectively.

Up to now, the solution for the `errorbar` updating in `matplotlib` is truly non-trivial, hope it be much easier in the future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the link provided by *Tong* and learned that there is a problem in his code - input of *self* variable is not needed. There is also a more generalized solution provided by *mitpre* - I used it and it works great. Below is the code for quicker reference:

```
def update_errorbar(errobj, x, y, xerr=None, yerr=None):
    ln, caps, bars = errobj


    if len(bars) == 2:
        assert xerr is not None and yerr is not None, "Your errorbar object has 2 dimension of error bars defined. You must provide xerr and yerr."
        barsx, barsy = bars  # bars always exist (?)
        try:  # caps are optional
            errx_top, errx_bot, erry_top, erry_bot = caps
        except ValueError:  # in case there is no caps
            pass

    elif len(bars) == 1:
        assert (xerr is     None and yerr is not None) or\
               (xerr is not None and yerr is     None),  \
               "Your errorbar object has 1 dimension of error bars defined. You must provide xerr or yerr."

        if xerr is not None:
            barsx, = bars  # bars always exist (?)
            try:
                errx_top, errx_bot = caps
            except ValueError:  # in case there is no caps
                pass
        else:
            barsy, = bars  # bars always exist (?)
            try:
                erry_top, erry_bot = caps
            except ValueError:  # in case there is no caps
                pass

    ln.set_data(x,y)

    try:
        errx_top.set_xdata(x + xerr)
        errx_bot.set_xdata(x - xerr)
        errx_top.set_ydata(y)
        errx_bot.set_ydata(y)
    except NameError:
        pass
    try:
        barsx.set_segments([np.array([[xt, y], [xb, y]]) for xt, xb, y in zip(x + xerr, x - xerr, y)])
    except NameError:
        pass

    try:
        erry_top.set_xdata(x)
        erry_bot.set_xdata(x)
        erry_top.set_ydata(y + yerr)
        erry_bot.set_ydata(y - yerr)
    except NameError:
        pass
    try:
        barsy.set_segments([np.array([[x, yt], [x, yb]]) for x, yt, yb in zip(x, y + yerr, y - yerr)])
    except NameError:
        pass
```